# java "failed to validate certificate" but clears a while later?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I've got an old java webstart app, and it appears one of the certs (possibly just an intermediate cert) it uses expired in December '23.  That is understandable, but the odd thing is that the app will how the "failed to validate certificate" message for about an hour or so sometimes, but then go away and the app just works for users.  If the certificate is expired, then I would expect this to be either working or failed not a sometimes working.  Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

I know that I can disable the certificate validation, but would just like to understand the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Without knowing more, we can only guess. Could it be that your app is calling another service which is the one presenting an expired certificate but the app calls it only at startup or only for some actions?

Comment: It's the same launch webpage startup for all users, so nothing particular to any user/time of day.  The error happens before the application has presented users a login prompt.  Some days are quiet with no users reporting issues, but other days I am getting lots of tickets.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if there is any potential inconsistency in what java could be checking for CRL.  Where depending on what load balanced list it hits sometimes it succeeds somehow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wish I could provide code or had code to resign thus not worrying abt expired certs, but this is a vendor provided software package that is no longer supported.  This means that I am pretty much on my own.